# Quotient space of Polynomial algebras C[X]

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ideals

How can I prove that the quotient $C[X]/I$ is finite-dimensional, where $C[X]$ is the algebra of polynomials and $I=P_n(x)C[x]$ is ideal generated by a polynomial of degree n? And how can I find the dimension of this quotient?
I know that $C[X]/P_2(x)C[x]$ is isomorphic to complex plane

Comment: Intuitively, if the degree of the generator of $I$ is $n$, then anything above of equal to degree $n$ can be rewritten as something of degree less than $n$. See if you can use this to help guide you

Comment: Do you mean that I can bring any polynomial of degree higher than n using the division theorem to a degree lower?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The division algorithm: for any $a,b\in\mathbb{C}[x]$, there exist $q,r\in\mathbb{C}[x]$ such that $a=bq+r$ with $\deg(r)<\deg(b)$ or $r=0$.

As an example, let's consider $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2+1)$.  The set of all possible remainders when dividing by $x^2+1$ is $\{ax+b : a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\}$.  (These are all attained and inequivalent modulo $x^2+1$.)  This is a two-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$.  The multiplication is multiplication modulo $x^2+1$ (equality modulo $x^2+1$, so $x^2=-1$):
$$
(ax+b)(cx+d)=acx^2+(ad+bc)x+bd=(ad+bc)x+(bd-ac).
$$

Comment: Yes, I know this theorem, but I just don't quite understand what kind of space remains in the end. Do we consider equivalent those polynomials that can be obtained by dividing by $P_n$?

Comment: Thank you so much! Everything became clearer. That is, the result will be a finite-dimensional space of dimension n.